# No room for 'favorite website(s)' on Careers profile?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I realize there is an "Articles" section, but that section seems a bit of an odd choice. If you read a particular blogger wouldn't it be better to just say "This is who I read" instead of picking a single article they've written?

I think the biggest thing that bugs me is it would seem odd for me to put my favorite website I read, Slashdot, down when the section is devoted to "articles." Even though Slashdot, and many other tech sites, offer great insight for some of us.

Maybe a change in section title or section description to allow for a bit more leeway in that section, would be better?

Answer (score 8):

This is already possible.

When you go to that section, "add an article or blog post you’ve read" allows entering a blog instead of just the blog post. Add whatever reason you want to as to why you read that particular blog.

On your CV it will show under the "Articles & Blogs" sub-heading of the "Reading" section.

Comment: You are right that blogs on their own can be added, but my issue was more with the heading and description for the section. I guess I'm being just a little pedantic over the fact that if I included Slashdot there, that is neither article nor blog.

Comment: Slashdot is a group blog